# How to set condition in dropdown list in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu

Here is my code for drop-down list part.

What should I add in to make the option selected when the value is matched with the option value? How to set condition like `'if value=50 ,selected = selected' ?`

```
<label>Quantity:</label><br><br>
<select name="qty" id="qty" value="{{ qty }}">
    <option value="50">50</option>
    <option value="100">100</option>
    <option value="150">150</option>
    <option value="200">200</option>
    <option value="250">250</option>
    <option value="300">300</option>
    <option value="350">350</option>
    <option value="400">400</option>
    <option value="450">450</option>
    <option value="500">500</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Are you using a scripting language or templating engine? PHP, Python, Twig, Blade??

Comment: Yes, JavaScript @fubar

Comment: Have you tried something like: `{{ qty == '50' ? 'selected' : '' }}`, changing the value for each `option`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

following code make the option selected when the value is matched with the option value.

```
<label>Quantity:</label><br><br>
<select name="qty" id="qty">
    <option value="50">50</option>
    <option value="100">100</option>
    <option value="150">150</option>
    <option value="200">200</option>
    <option value="250">250</option>
    <option value="300">300</option>
    <option value="350">350</option>
    <option value="400">400</option>
    <option value="450">450</option>
    <option value="500">500</option>
</select>

<script>
     $(document).ready(function(){
       $('#qty option[value={{ $qty }}]').attr('selected','selected');
   });
</script>
```